# Make python code highlighting for VSCodium equal to VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscodium

Migrated from VSCode to VSCodium because "Microsoft bad". Developing `python` applications seems to be missing some of the code colors like the modules in turquoise or local variables in light blue in the "Dark +" theme, visible in the comparison below:

[image]
*Left:* VSCodium. *Right:* VSCode

Is the right style of code highlighting Microsoft only or am I missing an extension? I tried `Manage`>`Settings`>`tokenColorCustomizations` but the available types like `comments`, `functions` or `keywords` are not python specific, so doing it manually probably won't do the trick.

### Edit #1

I seem to have missed [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75427890/vscodium-python-modules-have-no-green-syntax) which was posted prior to mine. So far I have not been able to make it work within this timespan (*summer 2023*), but I tried out suggestions and found a few things:

#### Suggestion #0: Forcing `Pylance`

Normally, `Pylance` is hidden from the VSCodium extensions, but you can still get it via the online VS marketplace as a `.vsix` download. Installing it finishes fine, but neither the advanced highlighting nor code completion/suggestions are shown (?). The output of `Python Language Server` is reduced to

> [info] (Client) You may install and use any number of copies of the software only with Microsoft Visual Studio, Visual Studio for Mac, Visual Studio Code, Azure DevOps, Team Foundation Server, and successor Microsoft products and services (collectively, the “Visual Studio Products and Services”) to develop and test your applications [...]

which is neither an error nor a warning, but maybe the confirmation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75432992/16740689), which basically says that a combination of `Pylance` and VSCodium is not possible. Also, adding

```
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,    
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```

does not seem to work for me.

#### Suggestion #1: ["Just use pyright"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76427040/16740689)

From the [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/installation):

> For most VS Code users, we recommend using the Pylance extension rather than Pyright. Pylance incorporates the Pyright type checker but features additional capabilities such as semantic token highlighting and symbol indexing. You can install the latest-published version of the Pylance VS Code extension directly from VS Code. Simply open the extensions panel and search for “Pylance”.

As if that isn't discouraging enough, installing `pyright` anyway fails with this error (*Vscodium 1.81.1 for Win x64*):

> Pyright has detected that the Pylance extension is installed. Pylance includes the functionality of Pyright, and running both of these extensions can lead to problems. Pyright will disable itself. Uninstall or disable Pyright to avoid this message.

Fair enough, as `Pylance` is installed and probably still configured in `settings.json`. However, adding `"python.languageServer": "Pyright"` there shows me a value error `Value is not accepted. Valid values: "Default", "Jedi", "Pylance", "None".`. As the docs redirect me to `Pylance`, I am not sure what to put in here to select `Pyright`. Additionally, this may not even tackle the original problem, as it only employs **static typechecking** and not **semantic highlighting** as mentioned in the [comments of the related post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75427890/16740689).

#### Suggestion #2: "Use Jedi"

Switching to `"python.languageServer": "Jedi"` and reloading the window changes nothing about the highlighting, but at least enables reliable auto-completion. Where `Jedi` is installed or where it comes from is a mystery to me, so I assume that it is built in. While this is an acceptable solution to having basic highlighting and completion, it also does not tackle the original question.

#### Suggestion #3: [Copy-Paste hackery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76227927/16740689)

This results in all sort of version errors if the default extensions are installed in VSCode and then manually moved to VSCodium. The former installs for 1.82 and the latter for 1.81. Reverting extensions to previous versions leads me back to suggestion #1.

### Further works

If it can't be achieved, then so be it and I'll use `Jedi`. However, I remember having an old laptop with VSCodium which was running `Pylance` fine, so it's either me messing up or it was a compatibility change over time. I will investigate this soon and add updates here.

Comment: I think this is related to the language server. If you still have Code installed, you could check by switching `python.languageServer` from Pylance to Jedi. [Pylance is not supported in unofficial builds](https://reddit.com/r/linux/comments/k0s8qw/vs_code_developers_prevent_running_the_new/).

Comment: Related? [How can I get VS's python syntax highlighting in VS code?](/q/45291759/4518341) There's [an answer](/a/65166674/4518341) about changing the colours manually; that might help.

Comment: @wjandrea so VSCodium is unofficial? Unofficial as in not backed by a tech giant? But thanks for the info, I'll try out Jedi.

Comment: Unofficial as in, not built by Microsoft. That's the whole point of VSCodium...?

Comment: What happens if you set `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` in your VS Code settings? Does VS Code then appear the same as the VS Codium appearance?

Comment: @user For me, that setting has no effect on Python syntax highlighting. (Oh yeah, I forgot to mention that before: I see the same thing as OP on Codium, and I'm using Jedi. Never used PyLance.)

Comment: To be clear, I believe Pylance adds the more detailed syntax highlighting on VSCode. Some of it seems to require introspection, like knowing that `os` is an imported name, but on Codium, Jedi doesn't seem to provide any of that, so you're stuck with basic TextMate-powered highlighting. That is, unless you want to do the [hack to allow Pylance](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/892#issuecomment-957850440).

Comment: @wjandrea unofficial means it's not the official Microsoft version, it's built from the same code just with the Microsoft tracking BS left out.

Comment: @Pioneer_11 I think you tagged the wrong person. I already said that on Feb 4

Comment: @wjandrea sorry I meant to tag wjandrea. I know that was the point you were making, I just wanted to clarify as from your response it's not too clear what how the builds differ

Answer (score 1):

I successfully have the same syntax highlighting by installing vscode and python extension (with Pylance) and then:

```
rm -rf ~/.vscodium-server/extensions
cp -R ~/.vscode-server/extensions ~/.vscodium-server/extensions
```

You can then remove vscode :)

EDIT: I had trouble with the latest version, this resolved it  https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1640#issue-1898772365

Comment: Are you able to get updates after using that trick? Seems like a great trick but I wouldn't want to repeat it and reinstall all my extensions every time I need to update my python plugins

Comment: No problem with updates since then

Answer (score 1):

Pyright gives the same highlighting as Pylance in vscode and it is available in codium