# VSCodium - Python modules have no green syntax

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscodium

Recently, I'm trying to move from VSCode to VSCodium,
and I found a problem is that the green coloring of modules are not in VSCodium (like the picture below).

[image: screenshot]

left: VSCode, has the green syntax / right: VSCodium, doesn't have the green syntax.

I saw some other screenshots on the internet that their VSCode also don't have the green syntax, so I think it's not a VScodium problem but I still can't figure out what makes them different.

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of [Make python code highlighting for VSCodium equal to VSCode](/q/75345501). Sadly, that one has no answers yet. See [/help/no-one-answers](/help/no-one-answers) for what to do now.

Comment: What happens if you set `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false` in your VS Code settings? Does VS Code then appear the same as the VS Codium appearance?

Comment: I just added some comments on [the other question](/q/75345501/4518341) with some more details

Comment: This is related to the python language server and vscode semantic highlighting. You only get green syntax if you also enable semantic highlighting and make sure the python language server is pylance.  ```"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
 "python.languageServer": "Pylance",```

Answer (score 0):

This is provided by [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).

You can add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to two settings:

- [Python Language Server settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_python-language-server-settings)
- [Editor semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-semantic-highlighting)

The green syntax will only be displayed when you need to set to the following at the same time.

```json
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,    
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

*That is, semantic highlighting is **enabled**, and the python language server is **pylance***.

The python language server setting defaults to `"Default"`: *Automatically select a language server: Pylance if installed and available, otherwise fallback to Jedi*. So it is possible to get green syntax without modifying this setting, if **pylance** is available on your machine.

The default value of the `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled"` setting is `"configuredByTheme"`: *Semantic highlighting is configured by the current color theme's `semanticHighlighting` setting.*, so whether to display green syntax may also be related to the theme you use.

Via @wjandrea's comment below on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75345501/make-python-code-highlighting-for-vscodium-equal-to-vscode):

> I think this is related to the language server. If you still have Code installed, you could check by switching `python.languageServer` from Pylance to Jedi. [Pylance is not supported in unofficial builds](https://reddit.com/r/linux/comments/k0s8qw/vs_code_developers_prevent_running_the_new/).

If **pyance** is not available in VSCodium then green syntax is not available on it.

*A similar effect may be achieved by referring to [custom color themes](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)*.